# PHP: Select dropdown option if array key exist

Tags: php, smarty

I need to select the access level to an amenity based on a previous database entry for column access with options "a", "b" or "c".

I am getting an array with **id_amenity** and **access** for specific offer, but struggle to output its result to match the select options.

In PHP I have this

```
   $available = lib::$db->GetAll("SELECT id_amenity, access FROM offers_amenities WHERE id_offer = $idOffer AND available = '1' ");
```

In the front I have it as so:

```
<option value="a" {if $available.access == "a"}selected{/if}/> Unlimited </option>
<option value="b" {if $available.access == "b"}selected{/if}/> Limited </option>
<option value="c" {if $available.access == "c"}selected{/if}/> Paid </option>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: vardump `$available` to see what is in there

Comment: The / at the end of the opening tag probably still has no place being there though.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it like this if anyone is interested.

```
<option value="a" {if $amenityaccess[$amenity.id_amenity] == "a"}selected{/if}/> Unlimited </option> 
<option value="b" {if $amenityaccess[$amenity.id_amenity] == "b"}selected{/if}/> Limited </option> 
<option value="c" {if $amenityaccess[$amenity.id_amenity] == "c"}selected{/if}/> Paid </option>
```

Comment: In your question you have only the variable `$available`. Now, in your answer you use variables `$amenityaccess` and `$amenity`. That is very confusing